# Why does AJAX json script return extra 0 (zero)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have an AJAX function in WordPress that calls a PHP function to return the value of a transient record in the Database.

When I call the function using jQuery, I receive the result however it always has an extra 0 (zero) appended to the value.

Here is my jQuery function:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {

        var AdvancedDashboardWidget = function(element, options)
        {
            var ele = $(element);
            var settings = $.extend({
                action: '',
                service: '',
                countof: '',
                query:   '',
                callback:''
            }, options || {});
            this.count=0;
            var url='';
            switch(settings.service)
            {
                case 'facebook':
                    if(settings.countof=='likes' || settings.countof=='talks')
                    {
                        ajaxCall(action,ele,settings);  
                    }
            }
        };

    var ajaxCall = function(action,ele,settings){
        opts = {
            url: ajaxurl, // ajaxurl is defined by WordPress and points to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{
                action: settings.action // Tell WordPress how to handle this ajax request
            },
            success:function(response) {
                //alert(response);
                ele.html(response);
                return; 
            },
            error: function(xhr,textStatus,e) {  // This can be expanded to provide more information
                alert(e);
                //alert('There was an error');
                return; 
            }
        };
        $.ajax(opts);
    };


        $.fn.advanceddashboardwidget = function(options)
        {
            return this.each(function()
            {
                var element = $(this);

                // Return early if this element already has a plugin instance
                if (element.data('advanceddashboardwidget')) return;

                // pass options to plugin constructor
                var advanceddashboardwidget = new AdvancedDashboardWidget(this, options);

                // Store plugin object in this element's data
                element.data('advanceddashboardwidget', advanceddashboardwidget);
            });
        };

    });
})(jQuery);
```

There are more helper functions involved however this is the main jQuery function that communicates with WordPress and returns the value of the PHP function.

The issue is that if the value is returned as "`99`" for example it will be returned as "`990`"

**Here is the PHP function that jQuery is calling:**

```
/**
* Get Facebook Likes
*/

public function get_facebook_likes(){

    echo 99;
}
```

If I change the above to `return 99;` I receive plain 0

Comment: Are you adding a number to a string when you should be adding a number to a number, either on the PHP end or the Javascript end?

Comment: Just to debug I have the the PHP function "return 99;". It still returns 990

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your function should use [wp_send_json](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) to encode the result as JSON and sent it back to the AJAX request handler. This will also stop the execution of any subsequent PHP too, so there is no need to use exit or die.

So, for your specific example, you would use:

```
/**
* Get Facebook Likes
*/

public function get_facebook_likes(){
   wp_send_json(99);
}
```

Comment: I know this question is old, but it appears high in Google so I have posted the correct solution here - just in case it helps anyone.

Comment: Yes Lewis I was racking my brain and you fixed it! Stupid 0 was throwing me off. I didn't know about wp_send_json until now...

Answer (score 3):

This is old question but I'm going to answer this. `wp_send_json()` function may help but not always. There could be some moments when you can't use this function. Like, when you load posts by ajax, you are getting some template part, you can use the function. That's why WordPress documentation suggests to make use of the `die()` function.

So in the end, your php function should look like this:

```
/**
* Get Facebook Likes
*/

public function get_facebook_likes() {
   echo 99;
   die();
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer. Not all AJAXed data types are JSON encoded. Some are plain text or html. As soon as I added `die();` to the end of my AJAX function call, the 0 disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug and view the actual net data transmitted and received. Determine if the error is coming from the javascript side or the PHP side. Copy the net request and paste it into a separate browser window to see the raw result. If it is PHP, pursue that. if it is the javascript doing something, let us know.

Comment: In the Firebug net data for the request "POST admin-ajax.php" I receive the result as "990". Would this mean it is the PHP aspect or the Javascript?

Comment: That means that PHP is the problem

Comment: Have just updated the main question to show the PHP function that jQuery is calling.

Comment: then you must be echoing 0 somewhere else before the output completes. do you die() after echoing where you know the code has finished or just leave PHP to figure it out?

Comment: Thanks for the info. No I haven't used die();

Comment: Thanks popnoodles. That was the answer. Added die(); after echoing the result and now get the correct response.

Comment: @Jason:  What calls `get_facebook_likes`? Where are you adding `die`?  If you are adding `die` to `get_facebook_likes`, you're curing the symptom, but not the disease, and making that function even less useful.