# PHP appends 0 at the end in mobile browsers

Tags: php, ajax, json

My website just stopped working this week all of a sudden. What I noticed is that the ajax call I'm sending to my server returns an extra '0' character at the end of the data when called from a mobile phone. `ie. {1:1, 2:2}0`

This doesn't happen in a desktop browser. When I try accessing the .php directly from the browser, I could see the '0' appended at the end. Again, in desktop browser, there's no '0'. In different mobile phone browsers, there is always a '0'. This screws up my ajax call because I am expecting a json return value but the '0' character is unexpected.

I tried adding `die();` and `exit;` at the end of my php handler but didn't make a difference. Does anyone know what else could be the possible problem?

UPDATE:
I am not using any php framework.

I have simplified the code to basically just this and still get the appended 0 at the end.

get_data.php

```
<?php
echo "ASD";
die();
?>
```

I, then, access it through the webserver http://domain.com/get_data.php and I see ASD0 in the page. I've accessed it directly to remove the possibility that it is a ajax call/jquery issue. I still have yet to try hosting a basic xampp server on my local machine and see if the same issue happens. Right now, it is being hosted in our webserver in register.com.

Comment: We're gonna need to see some code...

Comment: PHP per se can't detect the used browser and do something else based on that. Unless you're telling it to do that.

Comment: Do you use some libraries or bootstrap for example? I had a similar problem a while ago and it was based on bootstraps own js

Comment: As others said it has to be something inside your code that echoes that. Do you have something that detects mobile? Do a grep by echo or var_dump, maybe you left some debug code.

Comment: @MarcusRommel the OP said that is appended to an ajax call, I don't think that bootstrap can change servers response after being processed by js itself

Comment: this could be some weird character added by the editor.. can you try removing anything after php closing tag?

Comment: @Tapos there's nothing after the closing tag

Comment: Is this a WordPress site? This might be helpful: [Why does AJAX json script return extra 0 (zero)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536356/why-does-ajax-json-script-return-extra-0-zero)

Comment: @showdev it's not a wordpress site. I've added die() and exit as I've found in other questions but neither worked.

Comment: I'm curious, if you change your code to `exit(1);` does it still print `0`? Also, what mobile browser[s] did you find were affected by this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question I asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467118/php-script-has-extra-0-at-the-end-of-the-output-on-a-cellular-connection

Comment: @spybart I didn't realize at first that it only happens in ATT data connection. I had your original question linked in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit but not sure exactly why. It only happens when using ATT data connection. It works fine when using WiFi and other network service provider.

Same problem as [PHP script has extra 0 at the end of the output on a cellular connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467118/php-script-has-extra-0-at-the-end-of-the-output-on-a-cellular-connection)

Adding below line fixed the issue

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: I had the same issue with AT&T mobile using latest PHP and Apache and can confirm this solves it.